# Equivalence between binary and decimal precisions

Tags: binary

We have binary number with fixed precision(e.g. after comma 7 binary digits). How to find the minimum number of decimal significant digits after period sufficient for obtaining equivalent precision?
e.g. 11.1001001; equivalent decimal precision ? (3.???)

Comment: If your precision is 7 digits, i.e $1111111_2$, what is this number in decimal? This number in decimal is of course $2^7 -1 = 127$ and this has three digits, so maybe this could be a clue ...

Comment: I want to carry out Khachian's Ellipsoid Algorithm for Linear Strict Inequalities and Khachian proved suffices precision for binary representation, I want to generalize this result for decimal digits

Comment: Take the maximum number that is smaller than $1$(because after that 
number it is irrelevant) :$$0.1111111_2\\\underbrace{0.1111111_2}_{0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7}\\0.1111111_2=0\cdot 2^0+1\cdot 2^{-1}+1\cdot 2^{-2}+1\cdot 2^{-3}+1\cdot 2^{-4}+1\cdot 2^{-5}+1\cdot 2^{-6}+1\cdot 2^{-7}=0.9921875$$ Hence to be sure you have $100\%$ accuracy you need at least $7$ digits.

Comment: What do you mean with *equivalent*? If you want to represent your binary numbers exactly in base 10, you need need 7 decimal digits to represent $2^{-7} = 0.0078125.$

Comment: I want to implement the Khachian's Ellipsoid method and the problem came from that side. Are you aware about this method and what you can kindly suggest ?

Comment: I want to find sufficent minimal number of decimal digits after period for Ellipsoid algorithm !